# Polymer vertical layout core-collapse

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, core-elements, polymer-elements

I have a problem using `core-collapse` elements with layout attributes `vertical layout`
All collapse are opened and I can't close them. I set also opened="false" but the elements are still opened and not closable.

```
    <core-collapse vertical layout opened="false" id="{{test.name}}">
                <template repeat="{{user in test.users }}">
                  <paper-item style="margin-left: 5%" on-tap="{{collapseDevice}}">
                    {{users.name}}
                  </paper-item>
                </template>
    </core-collapse>
```

Using Polymer 0.5.. It's a bug in Polyer 0.5? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried omitting `opened`  instead of `opened="false"`?

Comment: It would be nice if you create online example of the problem, as Plunk.

Comment: I got it. It was maybe a bug. I used a complex collapse ( collapse with a collapse) and the first collapse doesn't set automatically the height to auto. So i had to do it and now it work's. :)